# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement for all the packages

Tags: python, django, pip

I have recently configured python3 for other application and running on the same machine where python 2.7 was running.. I see python3 applications are working fine with command 
`python -m pip install package-name` and 
`python3 manage.py runserver` command

But I am facing trouble with my existing application and new application with following issue while installing package

```
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 9.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting django-allauth==0.27.0
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-allauth==0.27.0 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django-allauth==0.27.0
```

This is the command I used,

```
pip install django-allauth==0.27.0
```

Anybody know how to resolve it?

This is the command output,

```
pip 7.1.0 from /Users/overflow/.virtualenvs/ion/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-th)

Answer (score 2):

Try installing another version:

```
pip install django-allauth
```

Make sure you're using the version of `pip` that corresponds to the version of Python you are using:

```
pip --version
```

Alternatively, be explicit in which version you use:

```
python3 -m pip install django-allauth
```

or

```
python2 -m pip install django-allauth
```

Comment: But I am having this problem for all the virtualenv in my machine after configure python3 I think

Comment: @overflow Does this fix it?

Comment: How to check this "Make sure you're using the version of pip that corresponds to the version of Python you are using"?

Comment: @overflow Clarified.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

first
and then

```
pip install django-allauth==0.27.0
```

Comment: Tried this as well still same

Comment: which version is your default python?

Comment: try this: python2.7 -m pip install django-allauth==0.27.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm little confused with you'r version problem, but you can choose you'r python vertion using `py-2.x` or `py -3.x`. For example:

```
py -3.6 -m pip install djangp-allauth==0.27.0

py -2.7 -m pip install djangp-allauth==0.27.0
```

Comment: I guess this is for windows.. I am using MAC/Ubuntu

Comment: Oh, sorry. Didn't think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by uninstalling PIP in each project and then reinstalling it.. Might not be a good solutions, but this works.